# Test multiple-product purchase with sandbox PayPal

Tags: testing, paypal, paypal-sandbox, eclipse-pdt

I have a webshop and im almost there, but I have a number of items for purchase which are downloadable content. I fixed so when a user has paid they are redirected to my pdt.php where they get a receipt, Now I written code for also displaying content if the item-id are == something. Now I wanna make a sandbox/test-purchase of all products that are downloadable ontent which are 28. I can create 28 buttons and have the id 1-28 but that seems stupid. How can I do this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [cart upload command](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload) method of sending transaction data to PayPal.  It's similar to standard buttons except that you'll include all items in a single form.

Alternatively, if you're familiar with web service API's I'd recommend using the [Express Checkout API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec).  This gives you more freedom over your checkout and provides more advanced features as well.